# Entity Framework Adding Duplicate Record to Table Related to a Another Table with 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm doing a database-first Entity Framework setup with automapping.

I have a table/model called Related Items:

```
public partial class tb_RelatedItem
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tb_RelatedItem()
    {
        tb_RelatedItem1 = new HashSet<tb_RelatedItem>();
        tb_RelatedItem2 = new HashSet<tb_RelatedItem>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RelatedItemID { get; set; }
    public byte RelatedItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int SharePointItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual tb_RelatedItemType tb_RelatedItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual tb_Sites tb_Sites { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tb_RelatedItem> tb_RelatedItem1 { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tb_RelatedItem> tb_RelatedItem2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have another SQL table that tracks Relationships between two records in the RelatedItem table.

This is table of two columns of foreign keys that does not created an entity created for it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_Relationship](
[RelatedItemIDP] [int] NOT NULL,
[RelatedItemIDC] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tb_Relationship] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RelatedItemIDP] ASC,
    [RelatedItemIDC] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,           
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So.. I'm trying to add a Relationship in code:

```
tb_RelatedItem c = GetPutRelatedItem(cItemID, cItemType, siteGUID);

using (var db = new RelatedItemsContext())
{
    //check if relationship already exists for parent
    var ris = GetRelatedItems(pItemID, pItemType, siteGUID).Where(ch => ch.ChildItemID == cItemID);

    if (ris.Count() <= 0)
    //add the relationship
    {
        //get fresh copy
        tb_RelatedItem parent = db.tb_RelatedItem.Where(u => u.RelatedItemID == p.RelatedItemID).FirstOrDefault();
        parent.tb_RelatedItem2.Add(c);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When my code runs to create a relationship, the parent and child values are reversed, and a copy of my child object is placed in the tb_RelatedItems table.

Any ideas on how to stop the duplicate records?

Comment: `c` does not seem to be attached to `RelatedItemsContext`. So it is inserted in the database when used.

Comment: That was it, tschmit007!  Thanks for the help.